# Building Forms using TableView in iOS?

Tags: xml, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am looking for a something which shows Form Building using TableViews in iOS. Which can have labels, and text fields. A submit button tht will store data in database etc features.

If there is any tutorial which uses NSArray/DataSource property, contains more or less such features, will be helpful to get me going.

Comment: why have you tagged this xml?

Answer (score 1):

it is worth creating a couple of custom cells, which you can reuse in other projects, with textField, UISwitch, and UIButtons in them. then depending on the table row you would return one of these cells. what is your experience with iOS development?

Comment: I tried going that way, but having issues with getting a pickerview in cell. My experience with iOS is of few months.

Comment: what issues were you having? and why did you want a pickerView in a tableCell? could you post some code that you were having issues with?

Comment: Pickerview doesn't load properly in a row of table view.

Comment: its not visible, or you cant interact with it or?

Comment: It doesn't fit in the cell. Once pops up, and then remains in same state after selecting a value.

Comment: how have you set the frame for it? you may need to note down the indexPath, and set the size for the cell in -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score -1):

Pretty much any iOS development book will show you how to build table views. Or read through Apple's tutorials and documentation.

Comment: My issue is not with building table-view, but putting controls like textbox, label, pickerview, slider etc in TableView cells.